# Passing path as input argument in matlab.engine

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-engine

I'm using the following lines of code to run a matlab function (main.m) (I:/xxx/simcode/xxx/main) in python (using matlabe engine
), which takes path as input argument

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.run("I:/xxx/simcode/xxx/main, ['I:/xxx/xxxx/xxx/task5'])
eng.quit()
```

But I get an error,

```
  self._result = pythonengine.getFEvalResult(self._future,self._nargout, None, out=self._out, err=self._err)
matlab.engine.MatlabExecutionError: Too many input arguments.
```

Could someone please suggest how to fix this?
I would like to run the main.m from python by passing an input argument which is a path.